# Optimising network connections of firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase documentation recommends including code snippet given at (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/networking#https_requests) to optimize the networking, but few details are missing. Like

> How exactly does this help?

> Are we supposed to call the function defined as per of recommendation
> or include this snippet deploy?

Any documentation around this would be of great help.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "call the function defined as per of recommendation or include this snippet deploy"?

Answer (score 0):

this is an example showing you how you would make this request, the key part in this example is the `agent` field which by nature isn't normally managed within your app. By injecting a reference to it manually, you are able to micro-manage it and it's events directly.

As for the second question, it really depends on your cloud function needs - some users set it in a global object that they manage with all cloud functions but it's on a by-use case basis. but ultimately isn't required.

You can read more about `HTTP.Agent`'s and their usage below:

- https://nodejs.org/api/http.html
- https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/http/Agent
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent